# Callback error (Key error) updating scatter.children in Dash while selecting a column for plotting

Tags: python, pandas, callback, plotly-dash

I am getting message "Callback error updating scatter.children" while running Dash app (my first one). Debugging shows: KeyError 'Hours'. 'Hours is my column in dataframe. Column name is OK, and data are plotted correctly, but error message is always there. I do not understand why I am getting it. Any suggestions are very welcome.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

app = dash.Dash()

df_percent = pd.read_csv('data/neo_percent.csv')

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Graph picker dashboard'),
    html.H3('select a patient'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='patient-selector',
        options=[
            {'label': 'R1', 'value': 'R1'},
            {'label': 'R2', 'value': 'R2'},
            {'label': 'R3', 'value': 'R3'}
        ],
        value='none',
        placeholder='Patient',
        style=dict(
            width='40%',
            horizontalAlign='right',
            color='blue'
        )
    ),

    html.Div(id='output-patient-selector'),
    html.Div(id='scatter')
],
)


@app.callback(
    Output('output-patient-selector', 'children'),
    [Input('patient-selector', 'value')])
def update_header(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)

# Adding first graph

@app.callback(
    Output('scatter', 'children'),
    [Input('patient-selector', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    patient = pd.DataFrame()

    if value == 'R1':
        patient = df_percent.iloc[0:6]

    elif value == 'R2':
        patient = df_percent.iloc[6:12]

    elif value == 'R3':
        patient = df_percent.iloc[12:18]

    return dcc.Graph(id='scatter1',
                        figure={

                            'data': [
                                {
                                    'x': patient['Hours'],
                                    'y': patient['pct_Lymphs'],
                                    'type': 'line',
                                    'text':patient['Name'],
                                    'hoverinfo': 'text + y + x'
                                    }
                            ],

                            'layout': go.Layout(title='Patient Data',
                                                xaxis={'title': 'time'},
                                                yaxis={'title': 'percent'},
                                                hovermode='closest')

                        }
                     )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the initial callback firing. Your dropdown value begins as `'none'`. There is no condition for that in the callback, so your initial value for `patient` is still:

`patient = pd.DataFrame()`

There is no `'Hours'` in that dataframe, so you get the error. Once you update the dropdown, it can hit one of your conditions to update the dataframe, and it works. Here is one way to solve that:

```py
    if value == 'R1':
        patient = df_percent.iloc[0:6]

    elif value == 'R2':
        patient = df_percent.iloc[6:12]

    elif value == 'R3':
        patient = df_percent.iloc[12:18]
    else:
        return dcc.Graph(id='scatter1', figure={})
```

Comment: Thank you @coralvanda, you have pointed exactly to the problem!  But for me worked a bit different solution. `else: return None` and then returning Graph if any of if/elif statements satisfied.